# Tizen Studio 3.3: Device Manager and Emulator Manager fail to launch due to "The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP120.dll was not found."

Tags: windows-10, redistributable, device-manager, tizen-studio

I have recently installed **Tizen Studio 3.3** (**web-ide_Tizen_Studio_3.3_windows-64.exe**) and also install all necessary packages through Package Manager. After the process of installation had finished, I tried to launch Device Manager and Emulator Manager, but failed because of the system Error: "*The code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP120.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem*".

[image: https://sun9-69.userapi.com/c854124/v854124666/11387c/c6upBOVxiHI.jpg]

[image: https://sun9-2.userapi.com/c851232/v851232666/1d516e/HClldY0-Efg.jpg]

However, this file exists in the folder **C:\Windows\system32** and all versions of **Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Versions** are installed.

[image: https://sun9-17.userapi.com/c851232/v851232666/1d5167/9AXwemkj8cM.jpg]

[image: https://sun9-29.userapi.com/c851232/v851232666/1d5156/DfHq-vaoR54.jpg]

Please, help me to overcome this issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also I found out that Device Manager and Emulator Manager does not reference to C:\Windows\system32 folder, but C:\Windows\SysWOW64. As I expected I did not find this file (namely MSVCP120.dll) in SysWOW64 folder, and copied it from system32 to SysWOW64. However, I have got the following error: (https://sun9-65.userapi.com/c854124/v854124694/1151cf/ZnvZokiCCoM.jpg)

Comment: coping from system32 to syswow64 is bad idea. system32 is 64 bit and syswow64 is 32bit. Uninstall all VC++2013 runtimes and reinstall them

Comment: Thank you! It works, but only for Emulator Manager! Speaking about Device Manager, after its launching this error also, fortunately, does not appear anymore but nothing happened. It is strange...

Comment: https://sun9-44.userapi.com/c854524/v854524659/116b68/ih1Z62yKkCM.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overall, I have found out how to deal with this problem.
First of all, I had to totally reinstall Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable. Thanks 'magicandre1981' for this kind of hint. It helps me to get rid of this kind of error: 
[https://sun9-65.userapi.com/c854124/v854124694/1151cf/ZnvZokiCCoM.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFHE3.jpg)

As for unsuccessful launching of Device Manager, where nothing happens after it has been clicked, I overcome this problem by changing the path from '**C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-13_windows-x64_bin\jdk-13\bin**' to '**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin**' in **Environment Variables**.

Answer (score 6):

You need to install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013 (**x86**)
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: That was the solution! Special mention that it should be **x86**, although you have a x64 system.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstall the vcredist_x86.exe even if you have 64-bit system. This solution also fix Tizen Studio 4.6 Device Manager.

> The solution is to update Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for
> Visual Studio. You can do it by the link
> "microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=40784". Recomendation:
> install vcredist_x86.exe even if you have 64-bit system. This will fix
> the problem.
>
> Moreover, check if you have no spaces in folder name, where you are
> installing SDK. The installation can be complited successfully, but
> you will catch errors like "can't resolve path", because of spaces.
> Thats confusing.

Reference:　https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/missing-msvcr120.dll-v3.1-emulator

Answer (score 1):

According to my experience, device manager and emulator manager was not working on open jdk11, 12, 13.
I have tried for several days and contacted with samsung developer support.
They asked me to install oracle jdk8, I did.
Now it is working well.
Hope it help to somebody who having such an issue.